# Firebase Recycler Adapter: App Crashes when getItemViewType() method called

Tags: android, firebase, listview, android-recyclerview

I am using Firebase Recycler Adapter and my app crashes when i add **getItemViewType()** and **getItemId()** methods to my adapter.

it works just fine if remove these two methods from my adapter but then recyclerview shuffles items during scroll.

Please help me fix this issue,

Thanks in advance!

**Exceptions/Errors:**

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:216)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2140)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1147)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:195)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6493)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1710)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:346)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:935)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:747)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:679)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:921)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
```

**here is my code:**

```
public class UserDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView datalist;
private DatabaseReference userRef;
private Toolbar mToolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_data);

    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.user_data_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("User Database");

    userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    userRef.keepSynced(true);
    datalist = findViewById(R.id.userdatalist);
    datalist.setHasFixedSize(true);
    datalist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<userdata, DataViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter
            = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<userdata, DataViewHolder>(userdata.class, R.layout.userdata_layout, DataViewHolder.class, userRef) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(DataViewHolder viewHolder, userdata model, final int position) {


            viewHolder.setEmail(model.getEmail());
            viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
            viewHolder.setPassword(model.getPassword());
            viewHolder.setPhone(model.getPhone());
            viewHolder.setSince(model.getSince());

        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return position;
        }


    };

    datalist.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}

public static class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    static View mView;

    public DataViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public static void setName(String name)
    {
        TextView g = mView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        g.setText(name);
    }

    public static void setEmail(String email)
    {
        TextView g = mView.findViewById(R.id.user_email);
        g.setText(email);
    }

    public static void setPassword(String password)
    {
        TextView g = mView.findViewById(R.id.user_password);
        g.setText(password);
    }

    public static void setPhone(String phone)
    {
        TextView g = mView.findViewById(R.id.user_phone);
        g.setText(phone);
    }

    public static void setSince(String since)
    {
        TextView g = mView.findViewById(R.id.user_since);
        g.setText(since);
    }
}
```

}

**userdata.class :**

```
public class userdata {
public String email;
public String name;
public String password;
public String phone;
public String since;

public userdata(){}

public userdata(String email, String name, String password, String phone, String since) 
{
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.since = since;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getSince() {
    return since;
}

public void setSince(String since) {
    this.since = since;
}
```

}

Comment: i have updated post please have a look thank you.

Comment: Why `getItemViewType() ` `return position`. It should return layout id . Or there should be implementation for `onCreateViewViewHolder()`.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit? Thank you

Comment: Do you have different views or all rows of firebaseRecycler have the same view?

Comment: All rows have same view!!

Comment: Then you don't need the `getItemViewType()` method. `itemViewType` is used when there are different views and you need to differentiate between them

Comment: But if I don’t use getItemViewType() method, it will shuffle rows when I scroll recycler view.

Comment: What do you mean shuffle rows? the only purpose of `getItemViewType()` is to tell the adapter that there are different views

Comment: Do you mean shuffle as in recyclerView items will change their order in the list?

Comment: Yes , recyclerView items change their order in list

Comment: That's not related to `getItemViewType()` in any way

Comment: So what should I do?